# Element-wise sum of arrays in loop python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to make a loop that reads some arrays and then it calculates the element-wise sum of the arrays. A function that does this for 2 arrays is the numpy.add. In my case, I want to build a loop to do this for more than 3 arrays.

e.g. 
file_1, file_2 and file_3 are arrays : [[1,2],[3,4]] , [[5,6],[7,8]] , [[9,10],[11,12]]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

# load files
x1 = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv')
x2 = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv') 
x3 = pd.read_csv('file_3.csv') 
# Calculate the sum of these arrays.
X = x1 + x2 + x3
```

The above works fine.
Goal: to make a loop that does the above.

Attempt:

```
n=4
for i in range(1,n):
    x = pd.read_csv('file_{}.csv'.format(i),header=None)
    print(x)
    x += x
print(x)
```

the result is not correct. Any tip?

Edit:
SOLVED the answer is below

Comment: @roganjosh my output is an array with same dimensions as the X1,X2,X3. In other words, it is the mean array of X1,X2,X3.

Comment: That's a great goal!  Good luck in your attempts.  Let us know if you have any problems with those attempts.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard The reason I asked is because I have a hard time with this. Do you have anything to suggest?

Comment: @ser These questions are most productive if you provide your attempts so that we can suggest how to fix your approach or suggest alternate approaches. What you have provided doesn't contain any sample data or expected output, so even if we did write this out for you we would be guessing.

Comment: @AndrewL I added my attempt and the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *

def my_mean():

    N=array([[0,0],[0,0]])
    numb = 4
    subjs=range(1,numb)

    for s in subjs:
        X= pd.read_csv('file_{}.csv'.format(s),header=None)
        N += X

    N = N / float(3)

    return N

X = my_mean()
print(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that we can read multiple lines on file like the below example, please try it.

```
    from itertools import izip
    for lines_from_firstfile, lines_from_secondfile, lines_from_third_file 
    in izip(open(firstfile), open(secondfile), open(thirdfile):
```

So open your 3 files in the method like above and then try adding the values i.e x1+x2+x3